# How to drop texts and images on a canvas? (Firefox 41.0.1)

Tags: firefox, canvas, drag-and-drop

The following code should output 'hello' in the console, when I mark either the text "Canvas" or the image "testimage.png" and drag and drop it on the canvas. 
But it doesn't work.

When I add the eventListener to a textarea, it does work. But it really should be on the canvas. :/

I do not assume it is not possible.

How to do it?
(The html file is on my domain, and the image file is on the same domain in the same directory.)

```html
<html><head>
<script type="application/javascript">
function someInits() {
    document.getElementById('canvas').addEventListener("drop", function( event ) {
        console.log('hello'); //event.target.id
        //event.target.style.opacity = "";
        }, false);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="someInits();">
<hr>Canvas: <br>
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
<hr>
<img src="http://example.com/testimage.png">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In firefox, you need to block the default behavior of the `dragover` event in order to tell the browser you're handling it.

[More info on how to handle drag events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Drag_operations)

```js
function someInits() {

  // block the default dragover
  document.getElementById('canvas').addEventListener("dragover", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }, false);

  //handle the drop
  document.getElementById('canvas').addEventListener("drop", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.style.backgroundColor = 'pink';
    console.log('hello');
  }, false);

}

someInits();
```

```css
canvas{border: 1px solid;}
```

```html
<hr>Canvas:<br>
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="100"></canvas>
<hr>
<img id="img" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200" draggable="true" />
```

Comment: @John for question 2, in the given link, see [this paragraph](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Drag_operations#droptargets) : "Most areas of a web page or application are not valid places to drop data. Thus, the default handling for these events is to not allow a drop." for question 1, according to MDN it is. For textareas, I'm not sure, but I guess that they are "valid drop targets" by definition yes, just like some `<input>` elements are.

Comment: Also, **an important note** images are by default draggable, but if you want to drag a non-standard HTML element, you'll also have to initiate the event `dataTransfer` property in the dragstart event : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Drag_operations#draggableattribute

Comment: yep, you'll get used to this form, and I didn't even sent you to the [specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#drag-and-drop-processing-model)

Comment: Sorry forgot to answer this comment... Yes, `<img>` elements, as any selected text node is by default draggable, so the attribute is not needed.