# How to access the image data after dropping an image from the html-part of a webpage onto a canvas?

Tags: firefox, canvas, drag-and-drop

This is a follow up question to
[How to drop texts and images on a canvas? (Firefox 41.0.1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34761204/how-to-drop-texts-and-images-on-a-canvas-firefox-41-0-1)

I simply can't find out how to access the image data of the image I dropped onto the canvas. I tried things like `data = event.dataTransfer.getData("image")`, but that all doesn't work.

```js
function addDragNDropToCanvas() {
    document.getElementById('canvas').addEventListener("dragover", function(event) { event.preventDefault();}, false);
    //handle the drop
    document.getElementById('canvas').addEventListener("drop", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log('something is dropped on the object with id: ' + event.target.id);
        // var directData=event.dataTransfer.getData("image");
        console.log(event);
        }, false);

 }
```

There surely is the image-data somewhere incorporated in the drop-event data? Isn't it???
(The image doesn't have an own id-attribute.)

Comment: Actually no ... Whether drag-dropped or not, img elements do not contain any embedded pixel data (well, no exposed pixel data). But after the img is drawn onto the canvas you certainly can `context.getImageData` to fetch the pixel data from the canvas.

Comment: An img element can be an image source for `context.drawImage` so you can draw the img element onto canvas like this: `context.drawImage(document.getElementById('yourImgElement'),0,0)`. You can store the id of each droppable element in its `dataTransfer` property. If you need help with drag-drop see this [MDN post](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Your user might do one (or both) of these two drags:**

- Drag an img element from your webpage onto the canvas, or
- Drag an image file from your local drive onto the canvas.

**If the image is being dragged from your webpage:**

1. Listen for the `dragover`, `drop`, and optionally the `dragenter` events.
2. When handling all 3 events, tell the browser you're handling the event with `event.preventDefault` and optionally `event.stopPropagation`.
3. In the `drop` handler, get `event.dataTransfer.getData('text/plain') which fetches the`.src` of the image that was dropped.
4. Create a new `Image()` object using the `.src` and `drawImage` to the canvas.

**If the image is being dragged from your local drive:**

1 & 2. Listen & handle the same events as in the webpage code.

3. Fetch the local image file(s) that the user dropped which have been placed in `event.dataTransfer.files`.
4. Create a `FileReader` and read each image file. The `FileReader.readAsDataURL` method will return an image URL that you can use as a `.src` for an Image object.
5. `drawImage` each new image to the canvas.

**Here's example code that allows both:**

```js
    window.onload=function(){

        // canvas related vars
        var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
        var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

        // dropZone event handlers
        var dropZone=document.getElementById("canvas");
        dropZone.addEventListener("dragenter", handleDragEnter, false);
        dropZone.addEventListener("dragover", handleDragOver, false);
        dropZone.addEventListener("drop", handleDrop, false);
        //
        function handleDragEnter(e){e.stopPropagation(); e.preventDefault();}
        //
        function handleDragOver(e){e.stopPropagation(); e.preventDefault();}
        //
        function handleDrop(e){
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
            //
            var url=e.dataTransfer.getData('text/plain');
            // for img elements, url is the img src so 
            // create an Image Object & draw to canvas
            if(url){
                var img=new Image();
                img.onload=function(){ctx.drawImage(this,0,0);}
                img.src=url;
            // for img file(s), read the file & draw to canvas
            }else{
                handleFiles(e.dataTransfer.files);
            }
        }
        // read & create an image from the image file
        function handleFiles(files) {
            for (var i=0;i<files.length;i++) {
              var file = files[i];
              var imageType = /image.*/;
              if (!file.type.match(imageType)){continue;}
              var img = document.createElement("img");
              img.classList.add("obj");
              img.file = file;
              var reader=new FileReader();
              reader.onload=(function(aImg){
                  return function(e) {
                      aImg.onload=function(){
                          ctx.drawImage(aImg,0,0);
                      }
                      // e.target.result is a dataURL for the image
                      aImg.src = e.target.result;
                  }; 
              })(img);
              reader.readAsDataURL(file);      
            } // end for
        } // end handleFiles

    }; // end $(function(){});
```

```css
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    #canvas{border:1px solid red; margin:0 auto; }
```

```html
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
        <body>
            <h4>Drag an image from below onto the canvas, or<br>Drag an image file from your desktop onto the canvas.</h4>
            <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
            <br>
            <img width="50" src="https://cfl.dropboxstatic.com/static/images/index/rebrand/logos/glyphs/glyph_french_vanilla.svg">
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: +1 for following the specs since if we don't handle the dragover event, the canvas element should not be droppable. I would just add that in the case of an "in-doc" `<img>`, one could prefer to store a ref of the element in a global var on its `dragstart` event, and then reuse it in the drop event.

Comment: @Kaiido. Agreed. Since the objective here of the drop is to draw the img on the canvas for further processing, passing the dropped img's id (or even a direct ref to the img element itself) is more efficient than newing up an image object based on the auto-passed URL. Thanks! :-)

Comment: @John. I'm assuming by "part of a [Google] link" you mean a web `.url` file [f.ex: like Google's `Image result for football.url` file]. Then yes, the football.url file contains a URL pointing to an image but itself is not an image file. *The drop event does not contain enough information to render the linked image directly*. One workaround is to use `FileReader.readAsText` to parse the Image URL out of the link file and then use that URL to create an image object to draw on the canvas. Good luck with your project!

Comment: Ahh, actually that makes your solution really simple. Since you have control of the html, just keep a table that links the associated img with each href. Then when you hear an href in the `drop` event you can look up the associated img and `drawImage(theAssociatedImg...` to the canvas. :-)

Comment: @John. From memory I don't think so, but you can use the F12 Dev tools to examine the drop event to see if there's img.src or img.id in there some where. Still, it's would easier & quicker to create a lookup table of links-to-img elements.

Comment: @John, that would deserve its own question ;-) `<a>` tags, just like `<img>` ones are draggable by default. When dragging such elements, the `text/plain` data of the event's `dataTransfer` is set to the dragged element's `href` or `src` value. When you do append an `<img>` into the `<a>` element, the `<a>` takes the event, and even if you block the default event on the `<a>`, this will also block the one of the inner `<img>` *(I don't know if this behavior is per specs)*.

Comment: Then, in the case of cross tab dragging, the only way to get the inner img's src is to get the `text/html` data, parse the returned string and extract the img's href... In Firefox there is also a `application/x-moz-file-promise-url` which does contain this info, but only for src pointing to a file, Google Images' dataURI won't be matched. Also, @markE, you may want to edit your answer, since the recommended and cross-browser way to get the `.src` of the image is to `.getData('text/uri-list')` and not `'text/plain'`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a set of (stripped down) tools I use to play with images

```
var imageTools = (function () {
    var tools = {
        canvas : function (width, height) {  // create a blank image (canvas)
            var c = document.createElement("canvas");
            c.width = width;
            c.height = height;
            return c;
        },
        createImage : function (width, height) {
            var image = this.canvas(width, height);
            image.ctx = image.getContext("2d");
            return image;
        },
        loadImage : function (url, callback) {
            var image = new Image();
            image.src = url;
            image.addEventListener('load', cb);
            image.addEventListener('error', cb);
            return image;
        },
        image2Canvas : function (img) {
            var image = this.canvas(img.width, img.height);
            image.ctx = image.getContext("2d");
            image.drawImage(ig, 0, 0);
            return image;
        },
        getImageData : function (image) {
            return (image.ctx || (this.image2Canvas(image).ctx)).getImageData(0, 0, image.width, image.height).data;
        },
    };
    return tools;
})();
```

After it is parsed you will have the global variable `imageTools`

To load and get the image data you will have to wait for the image load callback.

```
var image;
var imageData;
function loaded(event){
    if(event.type === "load"){
        image = imageTools.image2Canvas(this);
        imageData = imageTools.getImageData(image);
        // image data is now in the typed array
        // imageData.data
        // with imageData.width and imageData.height holding the size
        // there are 4 bytes per pixel in the form RGBA
    }
}
imageTools.loadImage(imageURL,loaded);
```

To put the data back into the image after using the imageTools

```
// image.ctx is non standard and is a result of the imageTools adding the 
// attribute ctx
image.ctx.putImageData(imageData,0,0);
```

To get the URL from the drop event which may be more than one image

```
var fileList = []; // a list of dropped images
// function called when images dropped
var imagesDropped = function(){
    fileList.forEach(function(image){
        // image.name is the image URL
        // image.type is the mime type    
    });
    fileList = []; // clear the file list
}
var dropEvent = function (event) {
    var i,j, imagesFound;
    imagesFound = false;
    event.preventDefault();
    dt = event.dataTransfer;
    for (i = 0; i < dt.types.length; i++) {  // for each dropped item
        if (dt.types[i] === "Files") { // content from the file system
            for (var j = 0; j < dt.files.length; j++) {
                // check the mime type for the image prefix
                if (dt.files[j].type.indexOf("image/") > -1){
                    fileList.push({  // add to image list
                        name : dt.files[j].name,
                        type : dt.files[j].type,
                    });
                    imagesFound = true;  // flag images found
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if(imagesFound){ // if images dropped call the handling function
        imagesDropped();
    }
}
```

Please note this is an example only and is not a cross browser solution. You will have to implement a variety of drop managers t cover all the browsers. This works on Chrome so covers the majority of users.