# Drag & Drop HTML for 2D canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, drag-and-drop

I have a little video game defined inside a canvas. For the elements of the game I have some constructors like this one:

```
myGamePiece = new component(30, 30, "Pacman.png", 10, 210, "image");
```

The thing is I wanna use the feature Drag & Drop to choose the source image when you drop the image on the game. The images are defined like this:

```
<img id="green" src="PacmanGreen.png" draggable="true"
ondragstart="drag(event)" width="30" height="30">
```

So I made this function to deal with the drop event to change the source image of the game element to the image you dropped. But the problem is the image doesn't change.

```
function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("image");
    if (data == document.getElementById("green")){
         myGamePiece = new component(30, 30, "PacmanGreen.png", 10, 210, "image");
    }
}
```

I'm sure I'm not defining that "if" the right way. Any recommendations? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Recreate the issue in in question in a jsFiddle.  You are not providing enough code for anyone to tell what the issue is.  I have no idea what new compnent does once its called

Comment: The only thing I need to know is if "ev.dataTransfer.getData();" contains an element like "document.getElementById();". Cause if not, that "if" case will never happen.

Comment: I think you'll find all you need in this answer and the comments below it http://stackoverflow.com/a/34823152/3702797