# How do I determine size and format of image dropped onto html page

Tags: javascript, html

So I make use of Html5's dropzone functionality to allow user to drag an image from another website, drop it onto a drop zone and then it displays in an as an image, fixed to be 300x 300.

But how do I find out the **actual** dimensions of the image and the image format so I can display in the caption below the image, (i.e 500 x 500 JPG)

```
.largeartwork img {
    max-width:300px;
    max-height:300px;
    min-width:300px;
    min-height:300px;
    border: 3px solid black;
}

<div class="largeartwork">
    <figure>
        <img id="res" src="style/images/new_artwork.jpg">
        <figcaption>
            New Artwork 
        </figcaption>
    </figure>
</div>
<h3>
    Artwork DropZone
</h3>
<div>
    <figure>
        <div id="dropzone">
        </div>
    </figure>
</div>

/** Drag/Drop Images from another webpage
*/
var dropzone    = document.getElementById('dropzone'),
send_btn        = document.getElementById('send'),
res             = document.getElementById('res'),
img;

dropzone.ondragover
    = function ondragover(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        dropzone.classList.add('dragover');
    };

dropzone.ondrop
    = function ondrop(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        dropzone.classList.remove('dragover');

        // try to get images from this dropevent
        img = retrieveImageData(e.dataTransfer);
        if (!img)
        {
            return;
        }
        res.src=img.element.src;
    };

dropzone.ondragexit
    = function(ondragexit)
    {
        dropzone.classList.remove('dragover');
    };
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this will help so haven't marked as duplicate but might be a good place to start if you haven't seen it already https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34816849/how-to-access-the-image-data-after-dropping-an-image-from-the-html-part-of-a-web

Comment: @DarrenSweeney thx, looks like there is a solution if using a canvas but I just have an img element so not too sure if I can make use of this or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get the droped file using `dataTransfer.items.getAsFile()`, you can get file name, type and lastmodified, then use the file to create Image object , there you can get  width and height of image.

```js
function allowDrop(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
}
function drop(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
  var data = event.dataTransfer.items[0].getAsFile();
  var imgType; 
  
  var img = new Image();
  if(data){
   imgType = data.type.split('/').pop().toUpperCase();
   img.src = _URL.createObjectURL(data);
  }
  else {
   img.src = event.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
   imgType = img.src.split('.').pop(); 
  }
  
  img.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = img.width + '*' + img.height + ' ' + (imgType || 'JPG');
  }
}
```

```css
.droptarget {
  width: 150px; 
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
  line-height:150px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="droptarget" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">Drop Here</div>

<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: Hi, thankyou that works for files dragged from desktop but not when drag an image from another webpage.

Comment: @PaulTaylor check the update answer, I changed snippet hoping the image you dragged from other webpage having extension.

Comment: @Drupal thanks that works, by only question is when dropping file it gives me "image/jpeg" - is there anything already inbuilt that would map tthis to jpg, i.e return to me jpg ?

Comment: @PaulTaylor check answer.